# How can I GetFiles only of 2 types?

Tags: asp.net, directory

Code:

```
string[] arrFileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(MapPath("..\\Pictures\\"), "*.jpg", "*.png");
```

Error:

The closest match to the overloaded method System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (string, string, System.IO.SearchOption) has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try below code using linqu:-

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(MapPath("..\\Pictures\\"), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".png"));
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following.......get data in two array and merge them

```
string[] array1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "*.jpg");
 string[] array2 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "*.png");

 string[] newArray = new string[array1.Length + array2.Length];
 Array.Copy(array1, newArray, array1.Length);
 Array.Copy(array2, 0, newArray, array1.Length, array2.Length);
```